# What does p-value of Mann Whitneyu t-test equal to 0 mean?

Tags: python, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm trying to perform Mann Whitneyu test on a dataset.
As the code is shown below, the data is grouped by different `Medal` value.

**Why the result p-value is 0?**

BTW, I'm new to all those things, it seems the statistic U value isn't necessary to interpret here? I just want to use the p-value to reject the $h_0$ hypothesis.

Any opinion will be appreciated.

---

Code:

```
df.info()
win_medal = df[df.Medal == 1]
no_medal = df[df.Medal == 0]

print('Group 0\n', win_medal.Height.describe())
print('\nGroup 1\n', no_medal.Height.describe())
print('\nMann Whitneyu Test')
stats.mannwhitneyu(win_medal.ID, no_medal.ID)
```

Output:

```
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 206165 entries, 0 to 271115
Data columns (total 15 columns):
ID        206165 non-null int64
Name      206165 non-null object
Sex       206165 non-null object
Age       206165 non-null float64
Height    206165 non-null float64
Weight    206165 non-null float64
Team      206165 non-null object
NOC       206165 non-null object
Games     206165 non-null object
Year      206165 non-null int64
Season    206165 non-null object
City      206165 non-null object
Sport     206165 non-null object
Event     206165 non-null object
Medal     206165 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(3), object(9)
memory usage: 25.2+ MB

Height in win medal group:
count    30181.000000
mean       177.642358
std         10.924188
min        136.000000
25%        170.000000
50%        178.000000
75%        185.000000
max        223.000000
Name: Height, dtype: float64

Height in no medal group:
count    175984.000000
mean        174.982578
std          10.430378
min         127.000000
25%         168.000000
50%         175.000000
75%         182.000000
max         226.000000
Name: Height, dtype: float64

Mann Whitneyu Test
MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=2272651387.5, pvalue=0.0)
```

Comment: It means the observed discrete value is more extreme than anyone other value you could have observed for the test statistic.

Comment: Welcome to CV! Please edit your answer with the button below to include your output as text, for mobile users and screen readers. You can indent your output with 4 spaces to make it appear as in the picture (mono-spaced). Also note that your variable naming is a little confusing (group 0 has the values equal to 1 and visa versa).

Comment: @FransRodenburg I've updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reported $p$-value of $0$ means the actual $p$-value is below the machine precision. *(Lower than the smallest number $\epsilon$, such that your program considers $0 + \epsilon > 0$).*

Such a low $p$-value means you have strong evidence against the null-hypothesis, so you reject it. However, with such an extremely large sample size, even the most minuscule of differences between groups would turn out to be very significant. Hence a statistical test might not be of much use at all here.

You have to ask yourself if a difference in means of about 3 is actually *relevant* to whatever these values represent. Especially considering the large spread (both have a standard deviation greater than 10). Without knowing what these data are, there is no telling whether this difference is relevant or not, even though it is 'very significant'.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the large sample size has such kind of influence. No wonder the `ID` column also has a 'very significant' p-value.